# In what order should you reference scripts?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I have a big problem if the scripts are located as usual

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I can not make the submit from js:

```
$('#table').get(0).setAttribute('action', '@Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Home", action = "Domain" })'); // it's work
$('#table').submit(); // this not work!!!
```

Comment: you may need to show more of your `HTML`. Is `$("#table")` a form element?

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you see an error? What is `#table`?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) say that submit method "can only be attached to `<form>` elements."
Then the problem don't is in the scripts order